# Twitter bootstrap modal window blinking

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I added bootstrap modal window, but it keeps blinking after 2 or 3 seconds. Here is the site www.rebellevents.com. Anyone please help me to rectify this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line in your css

```
.modal{
   overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now the blinking issue is over, but I'm not able to scroll the window.

Comment: I can't reproduce the second issue... Can you be more specific?

Comment: Actually now the problem is with small screen size, when we click on any modal button it popups and when we scroll other contents will override the modal window. If the content of the model window is too large close button and content is not visible.
Hope you understand the issue...

Comment: This html/css/js is a mess!
I recomend you to throw this code away, but if you want to keep fighting it, first add to the code of the modal window a max-height and a scroll on the modal-body element

Comment: Well, he used to have the code here "www.rebellevents.com".
Now it's offline, and there's no code provided here.
I'd love to have a more detailed solution but now I can't reproduce the issue he was having it's kinda imposible. =(